# Swing screen design, which Layout?

Tags: java, swing, layout

I am novice in swing and I want to design a screen of the type I have attached. The big right panel uses Card layout which gets displayed on various button clicks. I don't know how to arrange the components such I have 6 columns and the number of rows grows as I add more components. I would appreciate if someone could give me an idea of which layout I need to use or a pseudo code of how its needs to be done.

Thanks a ton !!!

[image]

**UPDATE :** Guys I have now moved my solution on each to use MigLayout. It is quite easy and it is very easy to use in case of dynamic components placements. Thanks one and all for your value time and answers.

Comment: Although some people find it hard to learn, GridBagLayout is your best shot with native LayoutManager's. MigLayout is an alternative (which is supposed to be easier to learn), if you can use third-party libs. Sometimes, JTable can also do a good job, if what you are looking for is a pure table-display.

Comment: Form-like layouts -> the JGoodies FormLayout

Comment: Guys my components will be added dynamically, so will these layout support that.

Comment: _my components will be added dynamically, so will these layout support that_ - what happened when you tried it?

Comment: The JGoodies layout allows for dynamically adding components if I remember correctly. And you might want to edit your question to emphasize such a requirement

Comment: @kleopatra - I have moved to miglayout to layout my component on each card. I am also using card layout. Thanks to you for your response on one of my earlier question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`GridLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html) is perfect for this: [`GridLayout(int rows,int cols)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridLayout.html#GridLayout%28int,%20int%29). A value of `0` will specify that the rows/cols can grow as you add more components.

A short sample from Oracle:

[image]

```
GridLayout experimentLayout = new GridLayout(0,2);//create grid any amount of rows and 2 coloumns

...

compsToExperiment.setLayout(experimentLayout);//add gridlayout to Component/JPanel

compsToExperiment.add(new JButton("Button 1"));
compsToExperiment.add(new JButton("Button 2"));
compsToExperiment.add(new JButton("Button 3"));
compsToExperiment.add(new JButton("Long-Named Button 4"));
compsToExperiment.add(new JButton("5"));
```

**UPADTE:**

If however you need a more flexible Grid layout see [`GridBagLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) as  Guillaume Polet suggested:

[image]

As you can see it allwows you to use more then 1 row/col per component:

[image]

```
JButton button;
pane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
if (shouldFill) {
                //natural height, maximum width
                c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
}




button = new JButton("Button 1");
if (shouldWeightX) {
                   c.weightx = 0.5;
}
c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
c.gridx = 0;
c.gridy = 0;
pane.add(button, c);




button = new JButton("Button 2");
c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
c.weightx = 0.5;
c.gridx = 1;
c.gridy = 0;
pane.add(button, c);




button = new JButton("Button 3");
c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
c.weightx = 0.5;
c.gridx = 2;
c.gridy = 0;
pane.add(button, c);




button = new JButton("Long-Named Button 4");
c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
c.ipady = 40;      //make this component tall
c.weightx = 0.0;
c.gridwidth = 3;
c.gridx = 0;
c.gridy = 1;
pane.add(button, c);




button = new JButton("5");
c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
c.ipady = 0;       //reset to default
c.weighty = 1.0;   //request any extra vertical space
c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.PAGE_END; //bottom of space
c.insets = new Insets(10,0,0,0);  //top padding
c.gridx = 1;       //aligned with button 2
c.gridwidth = 2;   //2 columns wide
c.gridy = 2;       //third row
pane.add(button, c);
```

Comment: GridLayout has one big inconvenient: the "cell" size is equal for all "cells", so you can't take advantage of extra-width (it will be equally distributed). Hard to say without knowing what goes in the "Table"

Comment: +1 Yes this is true, if this is what the OP intends then yes GridBagLayout is much easier. Updated answer

Comment: @DavidKroukamp -My components will be added dynamically, so will these layout support that.

Comment: @dareurdream Yes AFAIK all `LayoutManager`s support dynamic adding of components. Just remember to call `revalidate()` and or `repaint()` on the component to *refresh* the layout to reflect the changes made to the layout

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at either [GroupLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/GroupLayout.html) or [GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagLayout.html).  The former is probably easier to work with than the latter.

Comment: I have gone through GroupLayouot, but all my components are added dynamically, so will this layout support that.